# No catalog entry found for partition ID in database 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

I would like some help to fix the database problem.

I went to restore a database and I couldn't, so I executed `DBCC CHECKDB (N'DATABASE_NAME')` and the following result is displayed:

> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database
> 'DATABASE_NAME'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
> messages, contact your system administrator.
>
> Could not find an entry for table or index with partition ID
> 72057870436990976 in database 6.  This error can occur if a stored
> procedure references a dropped table, or metadata is corrupted.  Drop
> and re-create the stored procedure, or execute DBCC CHECKDB.

Some forums say to run this to try to fix the problem, but it didn't work:

```
DBCC CHECKDB (N'DATABASE_NAME', REPAIR_REBUILD)
```

I found an [article by Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-fixing-metadata-corruption-without-a-backup/) from 2011, he says there are only two ways to fix the problem:

> Export everything out to a new database or roll up your sleeves and manually fix the system tables.

Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Nope. One way is supported (export everything to a new DB) and one way is not (manually changing system metadata).

Comment: Just curious, can this be true "*This error can occur if a stored procedure references a dropped table*" and if OP knew which procedure, would this actually fix the meta-data problem in a supported way: "*Drop and re-create the stored procedure*"? Or is that one of those 0.01% chances of cases and Microsoft felt obligated to mention it in the error message for completeness?

Comment: Anything is possible.

Comment: @SeanGallardy, Thanks for the feedback, is the procedure of exporting to another DB 100% sure that the error will disappear?

Comment: It should. If it doesn't then that means there is a defect somewhere that should be investigated.

Comment: OK, I'll export everything then. Thanks